# If statement With One equals sign and Two Question Marks - PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

Just looking at the index.php page in Symfony 4. Just wondered if someone could clarify what this means?

```
if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
}
```

I'm thinking this this equivalent to the following but not sure thanks.

```
if(isset( $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] )){

   $trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'];
   Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
  
}
```

Comment: See: Null coalescing operator in the [PHP7 New features](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

Comment: The two codes are similar, but the original code will also set `$trustedHosts` to `false` if it's not set. This can make a difference if the variable is used later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's equivalent to:

```
$trustedHosts = isset($_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS']) ? $trustedHosts : false;
if ($trustedHosts) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
}
```

The difference is that your rewrite only sets `$trustedHosts` when `$_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS']` is set. But the actual code sets the variable always, giving it a default value if the `$_SERVER` element isn't set.